# Host Node.js on windows server

Tags: node.js, iisnode

I have windows server 2012 , and I want to run a node.js application on it. I would ideally like it to automatically start if we reboot the server.

I saw a solution called nodeiis but it doesn't look like it has been updated for over a year and the version is .2 . doesn't seem stable?

What is the current best practice for running on windows server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't even bother trying to integrate with IIS unless you *really* want to.  Instead, I'd try to daemonize the node process either by writing your own Windows Service wrapper or using [`node-windows`](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) which wraps Windows Service creation for you.